# Gunicorn timeout and streaming dynamic content

Tags: django, timeout, streaming, gunicorn

I have Django app using StreamingHttpResponse that fails when gunicorn worker times out. Basically extending timeout is not an option as streaming can take longer as it depends on network speed. Web server won't time out as is actually doing something but gunicorn workers seems to not recognize it.

I am aware of a choice between sync and async workers supported by gunicorn and using for example gevent.

it starts:

```
gunicorn -D -p /path/to/django.pid --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 --workers 2 -k gevent --worker-connections 10 --max-requests 100 myapp.wsgi:application
```

gunicorn log:

```
[2016-01-21 15:12:34 +0000] [30333] [INFO] Listening at: ...
[2016-01-21 15:12:34 +0000] [30333] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2016-01-21 15:14:22 +0000] [30338] [DEBUG] GET /url/1/
[2016-01-21 15:14:22 +0000] [30338] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
[2016-01-21 15:14:24 +0000] [30343] [DEBUG] GET /download/1/
...
[2016-01-21 15:15:43 +0000] [30333] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:30343)
[2016-01-21 15:15:43 +0000] [30343] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
[2016-01-21 15:15:43 +0000] [30343] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 30343)
[2016-01-21 15:15:43 +0000] [31203] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31203
```

nginx log

```
2016/01/21 15:15:43 [error] 23160#0: *10849 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream...
```

Why deploying the same app using fastcgi and flup never exposed that problem? Anyone could advice?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: I am afraid not. Single download works fine but if I run tests script downloading many files in parallel it still fail.

Comment: Are you running it on nginx or apache?  From what I have been reading on the documentation about gunicorn shows with streaming files that it requires a different set up

Comment: I am using Nginx to reverse proxy to Gunicorn. Which params should be different, what is missing? Could you explain more, please?

Comment: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html  halfway down the page it suggests ```If you want to be able to handle streaming request/responses or other fancy features like Comet, Long polling, or Web sockets, you need to turn off the proxy buffering```

Comment: Thank you for pointing into the doc. I tried various configurations. I have updated my original post, to make it clear. When buffering is off it times out, see debugging